# Assertion failed when creating CPaneDialog In MFC

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have a simple .exe MFC project and a DLL project with MFC statically linked. It exports the following function for creating a CPaneDialog:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void init_toolbox_gui(HWND ptr) {

AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

CPaneDialog *_gui = new CPaneDialog;
CWnd *p = CWnd::FromHandle(ptr);

_gui->Create(_T("DialogBar"), p, TRUE, (IDD_DIALOG1),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_LEFT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI,
    0);

}
```

I call this from my main .exe app class (derived from `CWinAppEx`) as follows:

```
// dll is a handle to the DLL lib
ToolboxInitFunc func = (ToolboxInitFunc)GetProcAddress(dll, "init_toolbox_gui"); 

func(m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
```

This fails in the following debug assertion, in `void CMFCDragFrameImpl::Init(CWnd* pDraggedWnd)`:

```
m_pDockManager = afxGlobalUtils.GetDockingManager(pDockSite);
ENSURE(m_pDockManager != NULL);
```

I can give the full code of that function but it is from standard MFC libraries.

This is the call stack:

```
toolbox-3d.dll!CMFCDragFrameImpl::Init(CWnd * pDraggedWnd) Line 106 C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CPane::CreateEx(unsigned long dwStyleEx, const wchar_t * lpszClassName, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagRECT & rect, CWnd * pParentWnd, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle, CCreateContext * pContext) Line 177   C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CDockablePane::CreateEx(unsigned long dwStyleEx, const wchar_t * lpszCaption, CWnd * pParentWnd, const tagRECT & rect, int bHasGripper, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwStyle, unsigned long dwTabbedStyle, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle, CCreateContext * pContext) Line 175   C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CDockablePane::Create(const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, CWnd * pParentWnd, CSize sizeDefault, int bHasGripper, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwStyle, unsigned long dwTabbedStyle, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle) Line 148 C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CPaneDialog::Create(const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, CWnd * pParentWnd, int bHasGripper, const wchar_t * lpszTemplateName, unsigned int nStyle, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwTabbedStyle, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle) Line 48   C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CPaneDialog::Create(const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, CWnd * pParentWnd, int bHasGripper, unsigned int nIDTemplate, unsigned int nStyle, unsigned int nID) Line 42 C++
toolbox-3d.dll!init_toolbox_gui(HWND__ * ptr) Line 45   C++
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the docking features "stand alone".

This docking stuff needs a specially prepared CFrameWndEx class. If the MFC project uses such a class you are forced to use the MFC dynamically linked, when you want to use a DLL.

The ASSERT you get is just an indicator that the current module (your DLL), has neither a frame nor a dock manager to support such dockable panes.

The reason is simple. The statically linked EXE and the DLL will just use there own representation of a CObject, so all IsKindOf calls internally used in the MFC will only work inside the module.

Comment: Thank you! However, I want to use my code with Runtime Libraries with static linking (/MT). Maybe I should use another strategy for exporting a docking pane from a DLL?

Comment: There is no way to use static linking when you want to use this features from the MFC. You should always use an extension DLL for this. BTW: Why using stoically linking. It cost more memory. Lesser speed in loading such multiple DLLs, less flexibility with the MFC features and and and...

Comment: But can I use Runtime linking as static also? i.e. /MT

Comment: You can do this only if you use the MFC and the CRT in a shared DLL version. What are the reasons that you insist in statically linking. When using stand alone programs that use standard DLLs this is OK. When using complex DLLs szenarios and plugin technology I would say that using the CRT in and MFC in a shared manor is the better approach.